# ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent is not receiving

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, event-handling

I have following application starter:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication();
        springApplication.setListeners(Collections.singleton(new MyListenrer()));
        springApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args)
    }


    public static class MyListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent>{

        @Override
        public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent applicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent) {
            System.out.println("invoked");
        }
    }
}
```

But my listener is not invoking.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication();
    springApplication.setListeners(Collections.singleton(new MyListener()));
    springApplication.setSources(MyApplication.class);
    springApplication.run(args) ///!!!!!
}
```

Comment: Please close your question by marking your answer as correct [Edit: when you can].

Comment: @FailingCoder, I can't accept my own answer during 2 days

Comment: I guess you can close it now?